# Efficiently generate pairs from a list of 10.000.000 integers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, memory, generator

I want to generate pairs from a list of 10.000.000 integers. I do it as follows:

```
from itertools import combinations
import random
pair = next(combinations(random.sample(range(1, 10000001), 10000000), 2))
print(pair)
```

This takes approximately 14 seconds in my machine to run. Why does it take so long just to bring up the first pair? I want to know what is happening in the background? To my understanding of how generators work, it wouldn't take so long.

Comment: `random.sample` has to actually construct a list of 10 million integers in memory; it doesn't produce a lazy generator that `combinations` could somehow draw from.

Comment: The `random.sample` of 10,000,000 I'd imagine is taking a bit of time. Did you try timing that separately?

Comment: If you want unique pairs (and depending on how many pairs you want) it's probably faster to nondeterministically generate pairs of random integers with `(x,y) = (randint(1, 10000000), randint(1,10000000))`, and check that `x != y` and `(x,y)` isn't already in a set of previously generated pairs.

Comment: @chepner and @juanpa.arrivillaga when I run `random.sample` elsewhere and call it from combinations, I can see what was missing now. Thanks very much!

Comment: In addition to @chepner's advice, you might want to look at `random.shuffle()` here as you are ultimately asking for a `random.sample()` of the entire range and in that case `shuffle()` will be faster than a 100% `sample()`.

Comment: Did you want @chepner to generate an answer with code based on their suggestion? I think it is likely the right way to proceed unless you ultimately want to generate most of the possible pairs.

Comment: @JonSG Oddly enough, using `random.shuffle` and `random.sample` take roughly the same amount of time. I didn't do more extensive testing, but I wonder if internally `sample` switches to `shuffle`, returning the first `n` items if `n` is large enough.

Comment: @JonSG I was just testing to see if I can solve some other problem using combinatorics. I can understand @chepner's other solution with set but it is not actually what I am looking for in this case. I will look into `random.shuffle()` as well. Thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: @chepner Interesting. I just tested `shuffle()` and `sample()` with 10 million range and there is not as big a difference as I was expecting but with `timeit` I did see `sample: 7.2365299 seconds` vs `shuffle: 6.3130961 seconds`